# Use conditional in WHERE

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, express

I have an app where I query data based on admin role. If the user is Superadmin fetch everything otherwise fetch based on that user role.

Here's my query

```
let sql = `SELECT * FROM DossierCompletMobile WHERE FoldersID LIKE
  CASE WHEN ${req.body.superadmin} = 1 THEN 
   // what i want here is pull all folders without exception
    %% 
  ELSE
   // here i want to pull folders that have that folderID
    'AD451340-E774-4F6C-9398-ADC8E496A792' 
  END`;
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution .

```
let sql = `SELECT * FROM UsersTracking WHERE FoldersID LIKE
  CASE WHEN ${req.body.superadmin} = 1 THEN 
    '%'
  ELSE
    'AD451340-E774-4F6C-9398-ADC8E496A792'
  END`;
```